# Writing git branches in a file

Tags: git, bash, ubuntu

I am looking for a Bash script to write 'all' my git repository branches in a file as follow : 
branches=origin/master,origin/master/feature/f1,origin/develop/feature/f2
something like following bash :

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/jenkins/mfnp
git fetch --all
git pull
git branch -r | awk '/origin\/MFNP/{printf "%s,", $1 }' | head -c -1 >>/home/jenkins/branches.properties
echo "" >> /home/jenkins/branches.properties
```

But this one doesn't work. anybody can fix it for me ?  or give me solution like this .

Comment: Why do you want them in a file?

Comment: this file is used by jenkins to deploy my favorite branch.The branches are going to appear in cascade menu select able by user.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:
`git branch -r | sed 's/^/branches=/' | sed '/->/d' | tr '\n' ',' | tr -d ' ' >> /home/jenkins/branches.properties`

May well be a more elegant solution but that does remove line breaks and excess spaces from the output of the `git branch -r` command. Hope it helps.

EDIT: the `sed` addition removes any line containing '->' so it should work no matter which branch you're working on when you run the command. Hope that sorts it for you.

EDIT 2: done :)

Comment: this works perfect . But it writes :"origin/HEAD->origin/master" also to the file which is problematic . Here is the output of your script:   branches=origin/master,origin/master/feature/xxxxx,origin/develop/feature/xxxx
origin/HEAD->origin/master,origin/develop,origin/feature/yyyy-86,origin/hotfix/0.1.14,origin/hotfix/0.1.15,origin/hotfix/0.2.1,origin/master,    can You modify it somehow that it doesn't write "origin/HEAD->origin/master" into file. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Edited the original answer, hope that fixes things :)

Comment: Thanks a million. But still doesn't work. The string "branches=" should be in the begining .Would you please modify it some how it produces :branches=origin/HEAD->origin/master,origin/develop,origin/feature/UDK_KBI-86,origin/hotfix/0.1.14,origin/hotfix/0.1.15,origin/hotfix/0.2.1,origin/master,